# Sliding menu div - click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, tabs, sliding

I wanted to create side tab slide outs for two subdivisions of our company on the new version of the website I'm working on. After a lot of research, I decided to make it relatively simple (or so I thought).

I created a div (#CMTabWrap, 245px) that wrapped around two other divs: #CMContent (200px) and #BNOCM_tab (45px).  I set the margin for #CMTabWrap to -200px (the width of #CMContent), leaving only the tab showing.  The HTML and CSS are working fine.

Beneath the divs in my HTML, I put the code below. On click, it should test the class of the object and move it in or out (as appropriate) by the width of the content, either making the whole kit and kaboodle visible or reducing it to just the tab.

I want to say that I ran the code through JSLint, and read several questions here along the same lines.  I applied some of the fixes, but still nothing is happening.  I have a feeling it's something obvious -- I'm not quite intermediate with JS and slightly more than a noob. Any help appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   /*global $, jQuery, alert*/
   $(function(){
   $("#BNOCM_tab").click(function () {
     $('#BNOCM_tab').addClass('in');
     var contentWidth = $('#CMContent').width();

     if ($(this).is('.out')) {
        $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('in');
        $("#CMTabWrap").animate(
            {"left": '+=' + contentWidth},
            "slow"
        );
    }
    if ($(this).is('.in')) {
        $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('out');
        $("#CMTabWrap").animate(
            {"right": '-=' + contentWidth},
            "slow"
        );
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: looks to me like you add the 'in' class immediately, and then if 'in', remove it and add the 'out' class.  Which means it will probably do nothing :P

Comment: Try using .hasClass() instead of .is()

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click-function `this` refers to the clicked element, so `$(this)` and `$("#BNOCM_tab")` is always the same. Also your second `if` should be an `else`, because now you just swap the classes from "in" to `out` as @wwwmarty pointed to. So yours (inside $(document).ready) could look like this:

```
<div id="BNOCM_tab" class="out"></div> // add class 'out to the tab

var $Wrap = $("#CMTabWrap"), // create a jQuery object only once, store it
    $Tab = $("#BNOCM_tab");

$Tab.click(function () {
    var contentWidth = $('#CMContent').width();

    // use .hasClass() for class check, note there's no dot in the name
    if ($Tab.hasClass('out')) {
        $Tab.removeClass('out').addClass('in');
        $Wrap.animate({left: '+=' + contentWidth}, "slow");
    } else {
        $Tab.removeClass('in').addClass('out');
        $Wrap.animate({left: '-=' + contentWidth}, "slow");
    };
});
```

If that won't work, add the relevant part of your html to your question or/and make a fiddle and post what exactly went wrong.

Comment: I had to make a couple of small changes, because it turned out I was clicking the wrap and not the tab, but your changes made things work great! Thank you very much for your help!